# Get line numbers with AddressSanitizer output?

Tags: debugging, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to get AddressSanitizer to produce line numbers in its stack traces. I've tried on by a Mac and a Fedora 19 system and had similar results.

Here is a simple program:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *buf = (char *)malloc(5);
    free(buf);
    puts("get ready");
    buf[4] = '3';
    puts("done");
    return(0);
}
```

And I compile it:

```
$  g++ -g -o x -fsanitize=address x.cpp
```

And I run it (llvm-symbolizer is in my path):

```
$ ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=`which llvm-symbolizer` ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1 ./x
get ready
=================================================================
==9309== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60040000dff4 at pc 0x40091f bp 0x7fff1b721140 sp 0x7fff1b721138
WRITE of size 1 at 0x60040000dff4 thread T0
    #0 0x40091e in main (/raid/nfs_home/xv32/asan/x+0x40091e)
    #1 0x3304021b44 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x3304021b44)
    #2 0x4007e8 (/raid/nfs_home/xv32/asan/x+0x4007e8)
0x60040000dff4 is located 4 bytes inside of 5-byte region [0x60040000dff0,0x60040000dff5)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fe4ae58636a (/lib64/libasan.so.0+0x1536a)
    #1 0x4008d8 in main (/raid/nfs_home/xv32/asan/x+0x4008d8)
    #2 0x3304021b44 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x3304021b44)
previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fe4ae58644a (/lib64/libasan.so.0+0x1544a)
    #1 0x4008c8 in main (/raid/nfs_home/xv32/asan/x+0x4008c8)
    #2 0x3304021b44 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x3304021b44)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free ??:0 main
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c00ffff9ba0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c00ffff9bb0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c00ffff9bc0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c00ffff9bd0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c00ffff9be0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
=>0x0c00ffff9bf0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa[fd]fa
  0x0c00ffff9c00: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c00ffff9c10: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c00ffff9c20: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c00ffff9c30: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c00ffff9c40: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:     fa
  Heap righ redzone:     fb
  Freed Heap region:     fd
  Stack left redzone:    f1
  Stack mid redzone:     f2
  Stack right redzone:   f3
  Stack partial redzone: f4
  Stack after return:    f5
  Stack use after scope: f8
  Global redzone:        f9
  Global init order:     f6
  Poisoned by user:      f7
  ASan internal:         fe
==9309== ABORTING
[r4 ~/asan 19:34:50]$
```

As you can see, I have symbols but no line numbers. How do I get line numbers?

In answer to a question, here is the `objdump -h x`:

```
$ objdump -h x

x:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .interp       0000001c  0000000000400238  0000000000400238  00000238  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .note.ABI-tag 00000020  0000000000400254  0000000000400254  00000254  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  0000000000400274  0000000000400274  00000274  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .gnu.hash     0000003c  0000000000400298  0000000000400298  00000298  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .dynsym       000001b0  00000000004002d8  00000000004002d8  000002d8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .dynstr       00000141  0000000000400488  0000000000400488  00000488  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  6 .gnu.version  00000024  00000000004005ca  00000000004005ca  000005ca  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  7 .gnu.version_r 00000020  00000000004005f0  00000000004005f0  000005f0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  8 .rela.dyn     00000018  0000000000400610  0000000000400610  00000610  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  9 .rela.plt     000000d8  0000000000400628  0000000000400628  00000628  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 10 .init         0000001a  0000000000400700  0000000000400700  00000700  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 11 .plt          000000a0  0000000000400720  0000000000400720  00000720  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 12 .text         00000224  00000000004007c0  00000000004007c0  000007c0  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 13 .fini         00000009  00000000004009e4  00000000004009e4  000009e4  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 14 .rodata       000000bc  0000000000400a00  0000000000400a00  00000a00  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 15 .eh_frame_hdr 00000044  0000000000400abc  0000000000400abc  00000abc  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 16 .eh_frame     00000134  0000000000400b00  0000000000400b00  00000b00  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 17 .preinit_array 00000008  0000000000600d98  0000000000600d98  00000d98  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 18 .init_array   00000010  0000000000600da0  0000000000600da0  00000da0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 19 .fini_array   00000010  0000000000600db0  0000000000600db0  00000db0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 20 .jcr          00000008  0000000000600dc0  0000000000600dc0  00000dc0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 21 .dynamic      00000230  0000000000600dc8  0000000000600dc8  00000dc8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 22 .got          00000008  0000000000600ff8  0000000000600ff8  00000ff8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 23 .got.plt      00000060  0000000000601000  0000000000601000  00001000  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 24 .data         00000070  0000000000601060  0000000000601060  00001060  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 25 .bss          00000008  00000000006010d0  00000000006010d0  000010d0  2**2
                  ALLOC
 26 .comment      00000058  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000010d0  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
 27 .debug_aranges 00000050  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001128  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 28 .debug_info   00001041  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001178  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 29 .debug_abbrev 0000038e  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000021b9  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 30 .debug_line   00000239  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00002547  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 31 .debug_str    00000a9a  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00002780  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
$
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer posted at [How do I get line numbers in the debug output with clang's -fsanitize=address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566416/how-do-i-get-line-numbers-in-the-debug-output-with-clangs-fsanitize-address).

You need to use the `llvm-symbolizer` or `addr2line`

Comment: GCC can print line numbers without external help, provided that you built with debug info.

Comment: @yugr sometimes it does not... I bumped in the problem even if I was directly compiling all .cpp files (no libraries or anything fancy) with `-O0 -g`. In my case even `addr2line` just reported a useless `??:0`. Found the offending line with `valgrind` ans it succeeded providing the source location (but `valgrind` is incompatible with `sanitize=address`). My wild guess is that sometimes the reported address is wrong or that `-fsanitize=address` in some cases breaks debug infos.

Answer (score 4):

One advantage of GCC over Clang is that it comes with a good builtin symbolizer based on [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace). So just get rid of `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` and `ASAN_OPTIONS` and enjoy user-friendly output:

```
$ g++ -g -fsanitize=address tmp.c && ./a.out
get ready
=================================================================
==30328==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60200000eff4 at pc 0x000000400985 bp 0x7fffeafad920 sp 0x7fffeafad918
WRITE of size 1 at 0x60200000eff4 thread T0
    #0 0x400984 in main /home/iuriig/tmp.c:9
    #1 0x7f1f99850f44 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21f44)
    #2 0x400848  (/home/iuriig/a.out+0x400848)

0x60200000eff4 is located 4 bytes inside of 5-byte region [0x60200000eff0,0x60200000eff5)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f1f9a5548a0 in __interceptor_free /home/iuriig/src/gcc-6.2.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:45
    #1 0x40093e in main /home/iuriig/tmp.c:7
    #2 0x7f1f99850f44 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21f44)
```

(above was reproduced on Ubuntu 16 w/ GCC 6.2.0).

Comment: In 2014, when I asked the question, it did not.

Comment: @vy32 Might well be the case, libbacktrace was added around that time.