# How do I get line numbers in the debug output with clang's -fsanitize=address?

Tags: c, clang, address-sanitizer

I am trying to debug a memory error detected by `clang` with `asan`, but missed by `valgrind`. But I cannot get my `clang` built binary to give me any useful debugging information. I can demonstrate this with a short test program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *a = malloc(8);
    memset(a, 0, 9);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

(Obviously this error *will* be picked up by `valgrind`, it's purely to show the problem with `clang`.)

I compile it with Clang 3.4-1ubuntu1 like so:

```
clang -fsanitize=address -fno-sanitize-recover -o test -O0 -g test.c
```

Sure enough, `./test` aborts and I see some debugging info:

```
==3309==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000eff8 at pc 0x43e950 bp 0x7fff168724f0 sp 0x7fff168724e8
WRITE of size 9 at 0x60200000eff8 thread T0
    #0 0x43e94f (/home/jason/Code/astest/test+0x43e94f)
    #1 0x7faa43c47de4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21de4)
    #2 0x43e6ac (/home/jason/Code/astest/test+0x43e6ac)
0x60200000eff8 is located 0 bytes to the right of 8-byte region [0x60200000eff0,0x60200000eff8)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x42cc25 (/home/jason/Code/astest/test+0x42cc25)
    #1 0x43e874 (/home/jason/Code/astest/test+0x43e874)
    #2 0x7faa43c47de4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21de4)
```

But what I really want to know are the line numbers where the error occurred, and where the memory was allocated.

How do I get this information from `clang`+`asan`?

Comment: [This page](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) my help.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That page led me to the solution of using `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.4 ./test`, which is much better than manually running `addr2line` for every entry in the stack trace. Do you want to post that as an answer, or leave it to me?

Comment: I Was going to post it as an answer but I did not have time to test it, let me post it now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If we look at the `clang` [AddressSanitizer documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) it says:

> To make AddressSanitizer symbolize its output you need to set the
>   ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH environment variable to point to the
>   llvm-symbolizer binary (or make sure llvm-symbolizer is in your
>   $PATH):

and shows the the following example:

> ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/local/bin/llvm-symbolizer ./a.out

As the OP noted, the install location may vary, but once you know where `llvm-symbolizer` is located the steps are the same.

Comment: Note that for recent Ubuntu users, this will probably be `/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.4` (or similar, depending on version); or you can add `/usr/lib/llvm-3.4/bin` to your path instead of setting the environment variable.

Comment: I could not find llvm-symbolizer in /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin. I am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Durgesh - you may have to install LLVM clang from a PPA or manually from source, although I can't recommend a PPA for you — unfortunately, the one I used to use was removed `:/`

Comment: @Durgesh - oh, did you look in `/usr/lib/llvm-x.y/bin`? (...where `x.y` is your LLVM version)

Comment: I have manually installed llvm3.1 as per the steps given in https://github.com/pacs-course/pacs/wiki/Instructions-to-install-clang-3.1-on-ubuntu-12.04.1-and-12.10. After that i have checked /usr/lib/llvm-3.1/bin for llvm-symbolizer. It's not in that directory. Do i need to install another version  of LLVM?

Answer (score 16):

Is [addr2line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648642/how-to-use-addr2line-command-in-linux) what you are looking for?

```
 $ addr2line -e ./test 0x43e94f
 some/file.c:1234
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes using a symbolizer with a version number will give the error:

```
ERROR: External symbolizer path is set to '/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-5.0' which isn't a known symbolizer. Please set the path to the llvm-symbolizer binary or other known tool.
```

This can be fixed by pointing to an unadorned `llvm-symbolizer` binary:

```
export ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/llvm-symbolizer
```

Then ran your executable as you normally would.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes everything (path to the symboliser, environment variable etc) will be correct, but still you won't get `file:line` formatted output.

So run

```
dsymutil path/to/your.app/Contents/MacOS/binary
```

and then run the app and you'll get nicely formatted output. This is also mentioned in the docs.

> Note that on macOS you may need to run dsymutil on your binary to have the file:line info in the AddressSanitizer reports.

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#symbolizing-the-reports

Answer (score 1):

For me, there is no llvm-symbolizer in /usr/bin, I need to first use

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.8 /usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer
```

to create the symbolizer and then add it to the PATH:

```
ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer ./test
```